# How to see my favorited questions in this app

Tags: support, bookmarks, ios-app

When I want see my “favorite” posts, it seems that I can only do that on the website. How can I see them in this app? Or is that just unavailable?

Any help will be sincerely appreciated!

Comment: Which app? iOS? Android? Mobile interface?

Comment: Hello, I use iOS $\ddot\smile$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the bottom of the app, on any page that displays lists of questions, you should see a bar where the rightmost button says “More” with three dots on top of it. Tap on that, and a link to reach your favourite questions should appear.

Comment: Thank you very very much!!!!